# ChangeNotifier not listening to value change

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

I want to notify the wrapper when a value changes from null to a number, but the wrapper seems not to receive the change. Check my code below:

```
class setID with ChangeNotifier{
String studyID;

void setStudyID(String study){
  studyID = study;
  notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

in main.dart,

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => setID()),
    // others providers here
    ],
  child: MaterialApp(
      home: Wrapper(),
    ),
```

in wrapper.dart,

```
final studyID = Provider.of<setID>(context).studyID;
```

When the value is changed in setID class, no value is received in the wrapper. Could anyone help me out? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the code from

```
providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => setID()),
    // others providers here
    ],
```

to,

```
providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<setID>(create: (_) => setID()),
    // others providers here
    ],
```

And in wrapper get the provider listener as

```
final studyID = Provider.of<setID>(context);
```

The issue here is ChangeNotifierProvider doesn't know which variable/class object to monitor. It should do the trick. For more info read the official documentation of [Providers](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)